# How to update dropdown dynamically in Dash?

Tags: python, html, button, dropdown, plotly-dash

I want the user to be able to add his own input in a dropdown. How can I update the dropdown values only when he presses the button to add the option? So far, the dropdown is updated only when pushing the button, but if he inputs "1234", the dropdown list will have 1, 12, 123 and 1234. How to send only the final result to the dropdown?
And also, when the user clicks outside the dropdown, its value erases. How can I keep the value?

```
import dash
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html

app = dash.Dash()
app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Dropdown(
        id='dropdown',
        options=[],
        value="127.0.0.1",
    ),
    html.Br(),
    html.Br(),
    html.Br(),
    html.Br(),
    html.Br(),
    html.Br(),
    html.Button('Add Option', id='button', n_clicks=0)
])


@app.callback(
    Output('dropdown', 'options'),
    [Input('button', 'n_clicks'), Input('dropdown', 'search_value')],
    [State('dropdown', 'options')])
def update_options(n_clicks, val, existing_options):
    print(val)
    print(type(val))
    if val is None or val == "":
        return existing_options
    else:
        option_name = '{}'.format(val)
        existing_options.append({'label': option_name, 'value': option_name})
        return existing_options


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True, port=8052)
```